# How to find mode of every n (50) rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mode

I have a dataframe with 8 columns and ~0.8 million rows. I want to find the mode of every 50 rows of a specific column (e.g. Column 5) in a separate dataframe. My approach looks like this.

```
for i in range(1, len(data['Column5'])-1) :
  splitdata = (data['Column5'][i:(i+49)])  
  mode_pressure[j] = splitdata.mode()
  i = i+50
  j = j+1
```

But I get "'int' object does not support item assignment" error. My df looks like the below

```
Col1 Col2   Col3     Col4        Col5   Col6    Col7 Col8
0   612458  6715209 671598606   101043  -56     224 16560   
1   612458  6715210 671598706   101038  -264    256 16696   
2   612458  6715211 671598806   101038  -144    192 16528   
3   612458  6715212 671598906   101043  -136    200 16576   
4   612458  6715213 671599006   101037  -232    104 16576   
5   612458  6715214 671599106   101038  -88     264 16904   
6   612458  6715215 671599206   101040  -200    176 16808
7   612458  6715212 671598906   101043  -136    200 16576   
8   612458  6715213 671599006   101037  -232    104 16576   
9   612458  6715214 671599106   101040  -88     264 16904   
10  612458  6715215 671599206   101040  -200    176 16808

Output: (assume mode of 5 values)
df_mode : 101038, 101048
```

I have written the same function in R. And R returns the latest (last) mode value as a single output for every set of 50.

```
i=1
j=1
while(i<=length(data$Column5)-1) {
  splitdata<-data$Column5[i:(i+49)]  
  mode_value[j] = modeest::mfv(splitdata)
  i=i+50
  j=j+1
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think need `groupby` by numpy arange for more general solution, e.g. working nice with `DatetimeIndex` with floor division:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 50)['Col5'].apply(lambda x: x.mode())
```

---

There is possible multiple values, so possible solutions are `Multiindex`:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 5)['Col5'].apply(lambda x: x.mode())
print (df)
0  0    101038
   1    101043
1  0    101040
2  0    101040
Name: Col5, dtype: int64
```

Or lists:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 5)['Col5'].apply(lambda x: x.mode().tolist())
print (df)
0    [101038, 101043]
1            [101040]
2            [101040]
Name: Col5, dtype: object
```

Comment: Cool! That looks simple. In the event of multiple mode values, I would need to take the latest (last) value alone. Is there a way for that?

Comment: @veggie crunch burger. I am out of my laptop, but `x.mode().tolist()[-1]` or `x.mode().iloc[-1]` should works.

Comment: Sure! Let me try that and get back.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot! On a side note, can you please tell me whats the problem with my approach using for() loop? I feel the logic looks fine but I get the error "int' object does not support item assignment".

Comment: In my opinion you need define first empy list before loop `mode_pressure = []` and then append each value change `mode_pressure[j] = splitdata.mode()` to `mode_pressure.append(splitdata.mode())`

Answer (score 1):

I think another solution (with `rolling`) could be this:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
df_mode = df['Col5'].rolling(window=50, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: mode(x)[0])[::50]
```

Comment: Cool! This works as well! Thanks. But the first answer is faster than "rolling"" window. It takes about 3-4 sec for the first and about 90 sec for this. But this gives some interesting applications with rolling windows..

Comment: Yes, actually in this way you still apply the mode on all windows(50 times more than the other solution)